# magento2 toolbar.phtml issue-not overriding

Tags: magento2, layout, template

Guys I'm stuck in the below issue for overriding core template file.

I'm trying to override default Magento search engine.
I want to override core `filter.phtml` and `toolbar.phtml`

I get the products rendered into the frontpage, but my custom templates are not being used.

**I get something like this:**

[image]

**I have to get these("Items", "Sort By", "Shipping Options") from** ***toolbar.phtml*** which i'm not getting

[image]

**Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\catalogsearch_result_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <referenceBlock name="catalogsearch.leftnav">
   <action method="setTemplate">
    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/list/toolbar.phtml</argument>
   </action>
 </referenceBlock>
```

**toolbar.phtml**
Is same code as core.

I doubt the block name in my xml, please suggest

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to add any xml at all if you just want to override the file out-rightly. All you need to do is copy the file over to your theme and then make the changes in the newly copied file.

So you should copy the file to:

```
app/design/frontend/Company_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar.phtml
```

Hope this helps.