# product/list/toolbar.phtml Invalid template file: error

Tags: magento2

How to solve the template error in system.log which says:

```
Invalid template file: 'product/list/toolbar.phtml' in module: 'Vendor_Module' block's name: 'product_list_toolbar' [] []
```

I have overridden the catalog search  module.

**In view/frontend/templates:**
I have oly result.phtml

**view/frontend/layout:** catalogsearch_result_index

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
  <action method="setTemplate">
    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/list/toolbar.phtml</argument>
  </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

**etc/frontend/routes**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route id="catalogsearch" frontName="catalogsearch">
        <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
    </route>
</router>
</config>
```

**etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="2.2.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        <module name="Magento_CatalogSearch"/>
        <module name="Magento_Swatches"/>
        <module name="Magento_ConfigurableProduct"/>
        <module name="Magento_Eav"/>
        <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        <module name="Magento_Store"/>
        <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
        <module name="Magento_MediaStorage"/>
        <module name="Magento_Config"/>
        <module name="Magento_LayeredNavigation"/>
        <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
</config>
```

How to override the toolbar.phtml
What should be my layout file contents??

**I heard we have to place our custom template in app/design/frontend/myvendor/mytheme..?**

I mean why do we have to keep our templates in theme folder? is that necessary? If so how ?

Comment: If i include, product/list/toolbar.phtml file in my template folder, my "catalogsearch/result/?q=keyword"  url navigates to catalog's toolbar page !

Answer (score 2):

Try this way :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
          <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/list/toolbar.phtml</argument>
          </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I was just add page tag and body tag in your catalogsearch_result_index.xml file.

Comment: have tried tat buddy..no use :(

Comment: your code is working fine in mine after update catalogsearch_result_index.xml file.

Comment: are u getting proper Catalogsearch and catalog pages rendered properly? like i have mentioned in this link  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125727/magento2-toolbar-phtml-issue-not-overriding

Comment: Could you please share your code, i want to see the file structure?

Comment: Not doing any changes in toolbar.phtml, just override it in my custom extension. and it works fine.

Comment: i have neither changed it... but its not working here

Comment: i was addd xml at [Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml] and template file at [Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar.phtml] which is copied from base theme.

Comment: Please share your layout file code

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
     <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
    <action method="setTemplate">
      <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/list/toolbar.phtml</argument>
    </action>
  </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>